# Efficient and elegant interface abstraction

Tags: c++, abstraction, forward-declaration, type-alias

I'm trying to create a common interface for two third-party libraries that have similar functionality, so that I can code against the abstract interface and select at compile-time which implementation to use.

I need this abstract interface to not add any overhead, meaning polymorphism is out of the question. It shouldn't be needed anyway, since there's only one actual implementation in use. So my initial attempt looked like this:

*AbstractInterface.h:*

```
// Forward declarations of abstract types.
class TypeA;
class TypeB;
class TypeC;

TypeA *foo(TypeA *a, TypeB *b);
TypeB *bar(std::vector<TypeC*> &c);
TypeC *baz(TypeC *c, TypeA *c);
```

*ImplementationOne.cpp:*

```
class ActualTypeA {...};
using TypeA = ActualTypeA;   // Error!
...
```

Unfortunately this results in a compile error, saying that TypeA is being redefined using different types, even though the forward declaration wasn't telling it anything more than that it's a class. So the next thing I tried was this:

```
class TypeA : public ActualTypeA {};   // No more error
...
TypeA *foo(TypeA *a, TypeB *b)
{
    return actualFoo(a, b);   // Error
}
```

Here, actualFoo() returns an ActualTypeA*, which can't be automatically converted to a TypeA*. So I have to rewrite it into something like:

```
inline TypeA *A(ActualTypeA *a)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<TypeA*>(a);
}    

TypeA *foo(TypeA *a, TypeB *b)
{
    return A(actualFoo(a, b));
}
```

The reason I'm using the helper function A() is so that I don't accidentally cast something other than ActualTypeA* into TypeA*. Anyway, I'm not thrilled about this solution because my actual interface is tens of thousands of lines of code, per implementation. And all the A()'s, B()'s, C()'s etc. make it harder to read.

Furthermore, the implementation of bar() would need some additional voodoo:

```
inline std::vector<ActualTypeC*> &C(std::vector<TypeC*> &t)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<std::vector<ActualTypeC*>&>(t);
}

TypeB *bar(std::vector<TypeC*> &c)
{
    B(actualBar(C(c));
}
```

Another way to go about all this, that avoids requiring any implementation-side changes:

*AbstractInterface.h:*

```
class ActualTypeA;
class ActualTypeB;
class ActualTypeC;

namespace ImplemetationOne
{
    using TypeA = ActualTypeA;
    using TypeB = ActualTypeB;
    using TypeC = ActualTypeC;
}

class OtherActualTypeA;
class OtherActualTypeB;
class OtherActualTypeC;

namespace ImplemetationTwo
{
    using TypeA = OtherActualTypeA;
    using TypeB = OtherActualTypeB;
    using TypeC = OtherActualTypeC;
}

// Pre-define IMPLEMENTATION as ImplementationOne or ImplementationTwo
using TypeA = IMPLEMENTATION::TypeA;
using TypeB = IMPLEMENTATION::TypeB;
using TypeC = IMPLEMENTATION::TypeC;

TypeA *foo(TypeA *a, TypeB *b);
TypeB *bar(std::vector<TypeC*> &c);
TypeC *baz(TypeC *c, TypeA *c);
```

This has the issue that someone might accidentally use the implementation-specific types instead of the abstract ones. Also, it requires defining IMPLEMENTATION for every compilation unit that includes this header, and requires them to be consistent. I'd rather just compile either ImplementationOne.cpp or ImplementationTwo.cpp and that's it. Another disadvantage is that additional implementations would require modifying the header, even though we don't have an actual interest in the implementation-specific types.

This seems like a very common problem, so I'm wondering if I'm missing any solution that is more elegant and still efficient?

Comment: You seem to be going to vast, heroic efforts to solve problems that inheritance was meant to solve.  Since you are looking for compile time interfaces, you will need to look at templates.

Comment: Calling an extra layer of functions is overhead, so it cannot be a solution to your problem.  In short, I suspect you are picking some random things as "don't do it it has a cost" and others as "sure do it it has no cost" without profiling or certainty.  Are the two interfaces really method for method and function for function and type for type bijective?

Comment: You can use tag-dispatch or SFINAE to choose the implementation at compile time, if the information to select the implementation is available. It is compile-time polymorphism, but I suppose you just want to avoid runtime-polymorphism.

Comment: @Yakk No, library that I'm currently using to implement the interface does not map to it perfectly. Basically I have a thin wrapper on top of the library. The cost of that layer is well justified. But now I want to use an alternate library to implement the same interface (with abstracted types). Adding overhead for this abstraction is not justified since the implementation is chosen at compile-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like C++ supports a way to define a forward-declared class as an existing class. So I ended up using the approach with casts (and helper functions) anyway. It became a 650 line change, but at least it guarantees not to add any overhead.

I think I'll suggest to the C++ standards committee to add a language feature for this (or simply relax typedef/using to no produce a redefinition error) to make it easier in the future...

Answer (score 0):

You can use traits.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<vector>

struct ActualTypeA {};
struct ActualTypeB {};
struct ActualTypeC {};

struct OtherActualTypeA {};
struct OtherActualTypeB {};
struct OtherActualTypeC {};

enum class Lib { LibA, LibB };

template<Lib>
struct Traits;

template<>
struct Traits<Lib::LibA> {
    using TypeA = ActualTypeA;
    using TypeB = ActualTypeB;
    using TypeC = ActualTypeC;
};

template<>
struct Traits<Lib::LibB> {
    using TypeA = OtherActualTypeA;
    using TypeB = OtherActualTypeB;
    using TypeC = OtherActualTypeC;
};

template<Lib L>
struct Wrapper {
    using LibTraits = Traits<L>;

    static typename LibTraits::TypeA *foo(typename LibTraits::TypeA *a, typename LibTraits::TypeB *b) { return nullptr; }
    static typename LibTraits::TypeB *bar(std::vector<typename LibTraits::TypeC*> &c) { return nullptr; }
    static typename LibTraits::TypeC *baz(typename LibTraits::TypeC *c, typename LibTraits::TypeA *a) { return nullptr; }
};

int main() {
    using MyWrapper = Wrapper<Lib::LibB>;
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(MyWrapper::foo(nullptr, nullptr)), OtherActualTypeA*>::value, "!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(MyWrapper::baz(nullptr, nullptr)), OtherActualTypeC*>::value, "!");
}
```

Comment: This appears to have the same issues as the solution using the IMPLEMENTATION macro.

Answer (score -1):

Write two wrappers around the libraries which implement exactly the same functions. Then compile and link only one of that implementations. There is a small catch: to get real zero overhead you'll have to make that wrappers header only and rebuild whole project when you change the implementation.

You can either use macros to select the implementation or you can make your build system to compile only subset of your sources.

Comment: Your solution seems to just repeat the actual problem. How do we write two wrappers that implement the same interface? The most obvious answer seems to be to use casts, but that's not very elegant. Is there a way to forward declare a type and then define it to be the same as an existing type?

Comment: My solution is to write two implementations, but to compile only one of them. You either use your build system to skip files you don't currently need, or put implementations entirely under #ifdef end leave only one of them.

Comment: In other words: if you want to build two variants of your application with different backend libraries, then it is a work for a build system, not for language tricks.

Answer (score -1):

"meaning polymorphism is out of the question"

Why? I would say that inheritance is precisely what you want… What’s wrong with polymorphism? Too slow? For what? Is it too slow for what you want? Or are you just giving yourself an arbitrary constraint? Given what I understood from your problem description polimorphism is just what you want! You want to define a base class B that defines a contract – a set of methods. Your entire program will know only that base class, never referring to the classes derived from B. Then, you implement 2 or more classes derived from B – C and D – that actually have code in their methods, actually do something. You program will only know B, calling it’s methods without caring whether it C or D’s code that actually make things happen! What do you have against polymorphism anyway? It’s one of the cornerstones of OOP, so you might just stop using C++ and stick to C...

Comment: It's a high-performance framework that is already used by multiple clients. I can't allow performance to regress for the current implementation while I abstract the interface to allow for a second implementation. Also, these implementations use third-party libraries that are out of my control, so I can't derive their classes from a common base class. I could wrap them, but then I'm back to needing casts to upconvert them.

Answer (score -1):

"I can't allow performance to regress for the current implementation"

Of course you can. However you can't allow performance to regress *too* much. Do you know exactly how much performance you'll lose with polymorphism? You will lose performance but exactly how much %? Have you tried implementing a test version with proper instrumentation just too be sure it's the polymorphic calls that are to blame for the slowdown? Are you aware of how frequently those polymorphic calls are made? Sometimes you can increase the performance not by removing polymorphic calls - which is an elegant solution IMO to the problem it tries to solve - but by making your interfaces less chatty: caching results, bundling requests, etc. You would not be the first that tries to eliminate an obvious solution S because S is 700 ms slower, only to find S was to be used 6 times per hour... :S

If all else fails you can have two different implementations of the same cpp file and have your build process run twice - once for each cpp version.

Comment: "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection... except for the problem of too many layers of indirection."